# Converting methods in model to scope : Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, scope, active-record-query

I have two methods defined in my model Project working correctly.

```
1.  def completed(user)
         Project.find_by_sql(["Select p.id from bids b LEFT JOIN tasks t ON b.task_id=t.id LEFT  JOIN projects p ON p.id = t.project_id where(b.bidder_id=? and b.status=? and p.status=?) group by p.id", user.id, 'ACCEPTED', 'COMPLETE']).count
    end

2.   def current(user)
        Project.find_by_sql(["Select p.id from bids b LEFT JOIN tasks t ON b.task_id=t.id LEFT JOIN projects p ON p.id = t.project_id where(b.bidder_id=? and b.status=? and p.status in ('LAUNCHED', 'CONFIRM', 'STAFFED', 'OVERDUE')) group by p.id", user.id, 'ACCEPTED']).count
    end
```

When I am converting these two into scope in Project model as

```
1. `scope :completed, proc{|user| joins("LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.project_id=projects.id LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.task_id=t.id where(b.bidder_id='#{user.id}' and b.status='ACCEPTED' and p.status='#{COMPLETE_STATUS}')").count("DISTINCT p.id")}`

2. `scope :current, proc{|user| joins("LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.project_id=projects.id LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.task_id=t.id where(b.bidder_id='#{user.id}' and b.status='ACCEPTED' and p.status IN ('#{LAUNCHED_STATUS}', '#{CONFIRM_STATUS}', '#{STAFFED_STATUS}', '#{OVERDUE_STATUS}')) group by p.id").count("DISTINCT p.id")}`
```

I am getting error as : `ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "p"`

Please suggest me, how to write these two scope statements correctly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a scope is the better solution to result a count because a scope is used in order to have a filtered list of objects.

Anyway, your error seems to come from you try to call a table called "p". "p" doesn't exist because this is an alias in your method that you haven't declare in your scope.

To solve this you just need to replace "p" to "projects".

```
scope :completed, proc{|user| joins("LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.project_id=projects.id LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.task_id=t.id where(b.bidder_id='#{user.id}' and b.status='ACCEPTED' and projects.status='#{COMPLETE_STATUS}')").count("DISTINCT projects.id")}
scope :current, proc{|user| joins("LEFT JOIN tasks t ON t.project_id=projects.id LEFT JOIN bids b ON b.task_id=t.id where(b.bidder_id='#{user.id}' and b.status='ACCEPTED' and projects.status IN ('#{LAUNCHED_STATUS}', '#{CONFIRM_STATUS}', '#{STAFFED_STATUS}', '#{OVERDUE_STATUS}')) group by projects.id").count("DISTINCT projects.id")}
```

I hope this help